# Flutter: Not Woring websocket in flutter on android device

Tags: flutter, websocket

My WebSocket good working on Ios, but not on Android...

my socket connect code :

```
IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chatting/1/',)
```

No errors, no responses from clients and servers,, only Android device..

I'm using Plugin `web_socket_channel: ^1.1.0`

I don't think my server is a problem ,, The same goes for the practice server.

Comment: Please share more of your code. How you are using the connection, how are you checking for data? Please follow the guidelines on questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried to follow [this tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets)?